# CoreData Error SIGABRT: keypath AttributeName not found in entity <NSSQLEntity EntityName id=2>

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data, nsexception

I use core data in my iOS App. I have two entities, "Commit", with attributes "commitID", "completionStatus", "contents" and "repeatStatus" as well as an entity "ToDoList" with the attribute "dateID". The two are connected via a relationship that relates many Commits to one ToDoList.

I get the following error every time. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the app, to no avail. I know this error is thrown after my application(application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) method:

```
2016-05-07 10:54:14.131 CommitToday[1836:47383] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath commitID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity ToDoList id=2>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001027d7d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010457bdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreData                            0x000000010242efff -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:nestIsWhereScoped:] + 1583
3   CoreData                            0x00000001023217e3 -[NSSQLGenerator newSQLStatementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:nestIsWhereScoped:] + 35
4   CoreData                            0x00000001024147b8 -[NSSQLAdapter _statementForFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:countOnly:nestingLevel:] + 344
5   CoreData                            0x000000010232167c -[NSSQLAdapter _newSelectStatementWithFetchRequest:ignoreInheritance:] + 316
6   CoreData                            0x00000001023212f6 -[NSSQLCore newRowsForFetchPlan:] + 118
7   CoreData                            0x0000000102320bac -[NSSQLCore objectsForFetchRequest:inContext:] + 524
8   CoreData                            0x0000000102320549 -[NSSQLCore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 377
9   CoreData                            0x0000000102405eaf __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 3311
10  CoreData                            0x000000010240f4dd gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 189
11  CoreData                            0x00000001024005ed _perform + 221
12  CoreData                            0x00000001023201b4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 500
13  CoreData                            0x000000010231e973 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 579
14  CoreData                            0x000000010244d6c2 __43-[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:]_block_invoke + 258
15  CoreData                            0x000000010240f4dd gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 189
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001050143eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000104ff8ef5 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 393
18  CoreData                            0x00000001023ff076 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator performBlockAndWait:] + 198
19  CoreData                            0x0000000102366127 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 199
20  CoreData                            0x0000000102365fee -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 222
21  CoreData                            0x000000010244d4bc -[NSFetchedResultsController performFetch:] + 524
22  CommitToday                         0x00000001022404e4 _TFC11CommitToday14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 164
23  CommitToday                         0x0000000102240d42 _TToFC11CommitToday14ViewController11viewDidLoadfT_T_ + 34
24  UIKit                               0x000000010319a984 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 1198
25  UIKit                               0x00000001031defae -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 54
26  UIKit                               0x00000001031df882 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 462
27  UIKit                               0x00000001031df9f4 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 126
28  UIKit                               0x00000001031e0c4d -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 890
29  UIKit                               0x00000001031e1d0b -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
30  UIKit                               0x0000000103390503 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 248
31  UIKit                               0x00000001030ba980 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 703
32  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107aafc00 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
33  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107aa408e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 366
34  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107aa3f0c _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
35  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107a983c9 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 277
36  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107ac6086 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 486
37  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107ac67f8 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
38  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026fcc37 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
39  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026fcba7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 391
40  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001026f211c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 524
41  UIKit                               0x0000000102ffaf21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
42  UIKit                               0x0000000102ffff09 UIApplicationMain + 171
43  CommitToday                         0x000000010223c302 main + 114
44  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010504892d start + 1
45  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you have more than one version of your core data model?

Comment: How would I find out how many versions of my core data model I have?

Comment: You will select you *.xcdatamodel file then on the right side click "Show the File inspector" then look at section "Model version"->"Current version" and choose your one

Comment: It's looking for an attribute named commitID on the ToDoList entity - which suggests your fetched results controller is configured incorrectly.  Show the code for that.

Comment: Thanks @pbasdf I found the error in a fetchRequest. If you post your answer I can accept it as correct.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas I'm glad you found the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath commitID not found in entity [NSSQLEntity ToDoList id=2]'

it seems to be trying to access an attribute named `commitID` on the `ToDoList` entity.  That suggests you have a fetch or fetched results controller that is configured incorrectly.